# Can two offices communicate if one uses IPv4 and the other IPv6?

Tags: ipv6

If I get an IPv6 from my ISP for my new office branch, will I be able to communicate with my old branch that is using IPv4?

Comment: Completely unrelated: I envy you.

Answer (score 5):

Provided that you get *both*, then yes.  You need IPv4 to communicate with IPv4 hosts and IPv6 to communicate with IPv6 hosts.

Technically, there is "NAT-PT", NAT Protocol Translation, to let you access IPv4 stuff when you only have IPv6, but that would need to be run by the ISP and I wouldn't want to try to set up a VPN through that.

So *adding* IPv6 won't break IPv4 stuff.  Having *only* IPv6 would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine (there's not a lot IPv6 around yet), but it depends on the implementation in your hardware and software:

- On the operating system side: No problem, all modern operating systems are dual stack, i.e. they support both IPv4 and IPv6 and choose the proper version automatically.
- You'll probably get new hardware, i.e. an IPv6 router. It's reasonable to assume that it will be dual stack, but you might need to configure it properly.
- <strike>If all else fails, you can still fall back to a [6to4 tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4) which practically wraps your IPv6 packets in IPv4 packets.</strike>